# org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread while authentication

Tags: hibernate, spring-security

I am using spring-security on top of a Spring-MVC application. Currently I am working on a project where I want to authenticate a user. I have already implemented userDetailsService, UserDetails. Now when I get the username from the HTML form, I am passing the same to the DAO, where I can findByUsername. As username is not the primary key, I am using a Hibernate query to extract the user based upon username. I am getting the following error, kindly have a look. Thank you.

Error code : (akshay is username)

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "akshay" does not exist
  Position: 639
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2198)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1927)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:561)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:419)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:304)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82)
    ... 65 more
```

UserDaoImpl :

```
 @Override
    public User findByName(String username) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("FROM User as u where u.username="+username);
        User p = (User)query.uniqueResult();
        return p;

       // User p = (User)session.get(User.class,new String(username));

    }
```

User :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="registration")
public class User implements UserDetails{
    private static final GrantedAuthority USER_AUTH = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER");

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "my_entity_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name ="my_entity_seq_gen", sequenceName = "MY_ENTITY_SEQ")
    public Long id;

@Column(name = "username")
    private String Username;

 @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
```

LoginServiceImple :

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class LoginServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{
    @Autowired private UserDao userDao;
    @Autowired private Assembler assembler;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException,DataAccessException {
        //    UserDetails userDetails = null;
        System.out.println("LoadingUSER");  // Debug purposes, remove later
        User user = userDao.findByName(username);
            if(user == null) { throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Wrong username or password");} //Never specify which one was it exactly
        return assembler.buildUserFromUserEntity(user);
    }
}
```

Any pointers would be nice. I tried multiple ways of queries, mentioned in the documentation, none of them works and I get the same error. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LoginServiceImpl` calls the `UserDao`, but obviously no Hibernate session is created for the current thread when that happens.

Try adding `@Transactional` annotation on the `UserDetailsService` interface or you can add the `@Transactional` annotation even on the `UserDao#findByName` method itself. That way a Hibernate session should be present when the DAO method is called.

I'm assuming that you have transaction manager set-up in your Spring configuration.

Comment: Thanks. I setup @transactional and I have transactionmanager bean. It went ahead. Atleast I have a session now. I guess something is wrong with my query. I am editing the error log. Kindly have a look.

Comment: Your username property in User class is uppercase (private String Username). Try renaming it to lowercase and it should work.

Comment: Thank you very much. You have been very helpful. Just one last thing. It is trying to find column as username, instead of looking for a row. I am accepting your answer already. Thank you. Please check edit.

Comment: I guess that's because the String argument you're passing to the query is not quoted. Ideally you should not concatenate queries like this. Use "FROM User u WHERE u.username = :username" and then bind the parameteter using query.setParameter("username", username).

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Unfortunately the HQL documentation is not something I can use directly. Thanks a lot. Have a good day ahead Burghardt.

Comment: No problem, glad everything is resolved now. By the way, could you also mark this answer as Accepted? Thank you :)

Comment: Done. I had forgotten that... ;-)